# How to load multiple files in ifc.js

Tags: javascript, ifc

Hi I must be the first person to ask about ifc.js in SO but someone gotta start this, i have multiple files coming out of my Revit file for different treads and all of them share the same coordination point, is it possible to modify the code to load more than one model into the viewer?

```js
const ifcLoader = new IFCLoader();
ifcLoader.setWasmPath("../");
const url = "STRC-B-L10.ifc";

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  ifcLoader.load(url, (geometry) => scene.add(geometry));
});
```

Comment: someone please help me add ifc.js to the tags as creating the new tag 'ifc.js' requires at least 1500 reputation

Comment: That would be very cool. Maybe we can talk about this in the [open discord channel](https://discord.com/invite/g7Uzn2KSwB) with the community to see if anyone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just load multiple models and the loader will be able to handle all of them out of the box. For instance, you can try opening several models in any of the live examples. You can also close them with the `close()` method.

We are building the docs right now, so don't hesitate to let us know of any suggestions you may have.

Really cool to see the first question about IFC.js in SO